# After upgrading to Fall Creators Update, fonts in RDP session are not clear

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, fonts

I use a vm (VMWare Workstation 14.x) to RDP into a remote machine (remote machine is running Windows 10 Anniversary Update).  My vm was running Windows 10 Creators Update and was having no RDP issues.  Immediately after upgrading the vm to the Fall Creators Update, the fonts in my RDP session are not clear.  Also, vertical lines appear randomly as I'm typing.  If I then highlight the text afterwards, the vertical lines disappear...but the fonts are still blurry.

[image]

I've restarted all machines (the remote PC, the vm, and my local host PC).  I've verified that "Font Smoothing" is enabled in the RDP settings.

What else should I be checking/trying?

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of what you mean?

Comment: Good question.  If I take the screenshot from within the remote computer, even though it looks fuzzy on-screen, the screenshot is actually clear on other computers.  So, the next step should be to take the screenshot from within the vm.  However...I think I'm narrowing down the issue...the issue only arises if I have the RDP session full-screen across all three of my monitors.  If I pick any two (even two with different sizes/resolutions), it works fine.  Pick all three and I get fuzzy text.  Point being...I can't seem to get a method of grabbing a screenshot that shows the issue.

Comment: I guess I could try with my cell phone.  :p  Let's see how that turns out.

Comment: Ok, added an example to the original post.  Forgive the quality.  If I highlight the text, all of the vertical lines disappear, but the text is still fuzzy.  You can tell by the "h" in "This," the "p" in "example," etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not exactly the answer I was hoping for, but I took the easy route and just reverted back to the previous Windows build (Creators Update).  Everything now looks fine in my RDP sessions. Strange.